# Landing page is showing "Scam Insight: Personal Information Risk" - how do I remove this error?

Tags: forms, google-ads-api

A landing page I designed is showing a Norton Anti-Virus "Scam Insight" error whenever they load the landing page I designed for them.

Here is information on the error they're seeing - https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v77065451_NIS_SOS_2013_en_us

The landing page is just asking for first name, email and phone number - it's just HTML and CSS with a php e-mail script for when a user fills out the form.

Any recommendations on how to remove this "scam" warning?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think thats only a problem by your system? Have you installed a browser plugin from Norton? Check it out.

Comment: It looks to be on the client's system. He's wondering why this is only coming up exclusively on his website. I tried explaining that it's a new site and that may be the reason why - but are there are any other suggestions to make the site more credible?